# V8 exception if isolate not entered in main

Tags: c++, v8

If I have a class System that initialize V8, the isolate, etc, and from the main I do:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    System system {};  // initializes v8
    system.callJsFunction();
}
```

I get an exception when trying to call the JS `Function`. Yes the function is stored as `Persistent<Function>`. However, if I initialize v8 and enter the isolate scope in the main:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // initialize V8
  v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);
  v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
  std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
  v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
  v8::V8::Initialize();

  // Create the isolate
  Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
  create_params.array_buffer_allocator = v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
  Isolate *isolate = Isolate::New(create_params);

  // Enter the isolate scope
  Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);

  System system {};
  system.callJsFunction();
}
```

It works perfectly. So the question is, how can I enter the isolate scope in the System's constructor and remain in it during the entire execution of the program. I tried to manually `Enter` in it but it doesn't work. The isolate is of course stored in a member of System so I can access it.

Comment: At first glance, there is no reason for this to be the case. So, you probably messed up when you put this code in `System`. Unfortunately, we can see _literally nothing of its implementation_. So, for help, as usual, you will need to present your [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the definition of `Isolate::Scope`, you'll see that it's just a small convenience thingie that does `isolate->Enter()` in its constructor and `isolate->Exit()` in its destructor. The reason it exists is that you typically want these calls to happen in (possibly nested) pairs, and such a helper object is the easiest and safest way to ensure that (similar to the "RAII" pattern).

So if you have more complex lifetime management requirements, you can drop the `Isolate::Scope` entirely, and simply call `Enter()` and `Exit()` manually at the right times.

That said, you only stated that you "get an exception" without giving any further details about the type of problem (is it really an *exception*? Or an assertion failure? Or a crash/segfault?), so the above may or may not be the problem. Please post a complete example, and more details about the type of problem you're encountering (error message? stack trace?). If you haven't done it yet, compiling a Debug build and running it in a debugger of your choice might also provide valuable insight -- you might even be able to see what the problem is ;-)

Comment: The 2nd part of this should be in a comment instead.